# Why 2-methyl-1-propene's halohydrin formation does not involve steric effect?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides

This concerns Marc Loudon's Organic Chemistry 6th Edition's 5.2 page 187.

Consider 2-methyl-1-propene and its halohydrin formation mechanism. Usually, there will be formation of bromonium, where I assume there is no way that solvent stabilization will create carboncation.

$Q:$ Why does not hydronium attack C1 from opposite side of bromide of bromonium ion to open the ring? Consider swapping methyl group at C2 position by t-butyl group. I would expect significant steric hindrance from 2 t-butyl groups and this would force ring opening attack at C1 position as attacking happens at opposite side of bromide. If I remember correctly from Sunderberg's Advanced Organic Chemistry reading on bromonium cation, there is possibility of steric hindrance happening.

Comment: There is a steric effect, but it cuts both ways - bromine is large and its symmetric coordination to both C atoms would also cause greater clash between methyl groups. Essentially, this thing is like t-butyl cation stabilised by neighbouring Br.